# Saving ToggleButton state in ListView by using SharedPreferences

Tags: android, listview, sharedpreferences, baseadapter, togglebutton

I want to save my ToggleButton state by SharedPreferences at this below codes.
Please guide me.
Thanks so much.

```
public class MyAdapterList extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context context;
    private List text;



    public MyAdapterList(Context context, List text) {
        this.context = context;
        this.text = text;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return text.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return text.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_view, null, false);
        TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        tv.setText(text.get(position));
        Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/b_titr.ttf");
        tv.setTypeface(tf);
        tv.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#003366"));
        tv.setTypeface(tv.getTypeface(), Typeface.BOLD);


        final ToggleButton toggleButton = (ToggleButton) view.findViewById(R.id.t_button);

        final MyDatabaseHelper myDatabaseHelper = new MyDatabaseHelper(context);

        toggleButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.favorite_not_selected);

        toggleButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (toggleButton.isChecked()) {


                    myDatabaseHelper.insert(text.get(position));

                    toggleButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.favorite_selected);
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Was added to the list of favorites", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                } else {


                    myDatabaseHelper.deletedData(text.get(position));
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Removed from favorites", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    toggleButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.favorite_not_selected);


                }

            }
        });



        return view;


    }


}
```

Comment: you mean you want ot do it for all the items in the list?

Comment: bro please check my answer

Comment: You need to store each value in the database, you cannot use preference as you will save only one value and not all the value for each item

Answer (score 2):

you can save toggle button state  using below code

```
   final   SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        ToggleButton toggle = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggle);
        toggle.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

                prefs.edit().putBoolean("value", isChecked).commit();
            }
        });
```

to get them back use

```
 Boolean value = prefs.getBoolean("value", false);
```

Comment: let me know your result

Comment: But it will save only one state, not all the state of each item

Comment: K bro i undenstand your.problem iwill  catch you later

Answer (score 2):

```
static ArrayList<String> toogleValue=new ArrayList<String>();

 ToggleButton toggle = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggle);
if(toogleValue.contains("id"))
{
toggle.setChecked(true)
}else
{
toggle.setChecked(false);
}

        toggle.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
           @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked)       {
         if(isChecked)
{
toogleValue.add("id")
}else
{
if(toogleValue.contains(id))
toogleValue.remove("id")
 }             
            }
        });
I hope its help you.
```

Answer (score 0):

If i got it correct
Store the checked item in database of some where with the unique key(like;- name if it is unique).. get the list of checked though constructor and check in `getview()` if exists than make it checked otherwise make it unchecked.. 
You can use shared preferences too.. the both techniques need a unique value.

Answer (score 0):

Saving a particular state is very easy with Booleans and a switch statement inside an onClick.

```
private Boolean toggleBtn1;
private Boolean toggleBtn2;
private Boolean isChecked;
```

In your getView:

```
toggleBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                isChecked = ((ToggleButton)v).isChecked();

                toggleBtn.setTag(position);

                String pos = String.valueOf(position);

                switch (pos){

                    case "0" :

                        if (isChecked){

                            toggleBtn1 = true;

                        } else {

                            toggleBtn1 = false;

                        }

                    case "1" :

                        if (isChecked){

                            toggleBtn2 = true;

                        } else {

                            toggleBtn2 = false;

                        }

                }

            }
        });
```

Save the boolean outside the getView.